# Including other characters and symbols in a SQL Server auto incrementing key column

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have started to working on a project. I don't have a lot experiences except basic information. I just want to ask can I use symbols in primary key column like `2015/1234` etc. These are file numbers and must be unique so I've decided to make them primary keys but I am not sure that I can use symbol and if I can use can I use auto increment like

```
2015/1234, 2015/1235 ... etc.
```

Where 2015 is a year number. The second sequence number must be reset to 1 each new year.

Edit: and if can do all which data type should I use for?

Comment: is 2015 will me must as a prefix or it will change after year as `2016`

Comment: yes it will change as 2016, 2017 ....

Comment: see my answer just run as a test table in your DB you get your result

Comment: Does your sequence number need to reset back to 1 at the start of every new year?

Comment: yeah it must be reset to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your file number a Primary Key, by changing the type of `FileNumber` to `VARCHAR(x)`, but assuming you want the `sequence part` (i.e. `1234`) of the file number to reset each year you wouldn't be able to leverage an identity column (Sql Server's auto incrementing value) as this will continue to increase after each year.

You could retain a `VARCHAR FileNumber` PK and manage the file number generation yourself, but I would recommend against this - its bad for concurrency, since two writers inserting concurrently would need to contend for the 'next' value of the sequence number - this often results in a horrid, locked `SELECT MAX...` query before an insert, or an external 'next value' table, although in Sql Server 2012+, [a Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) would manage this for you.

Instead, I would recommend just using a surrogate integral identity (e.g. `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` as a PK - Sql Server will deal with concurrency, and it is narrower for other FK's to reference your table.

Then, add your encoded natural / composite `FileNumber` field, and include an additional unique key constraint column, or better, just break `FileNumber` into its component parts as two separate columns, viz `Year int` and `SequenceInYear int`. You can always then use a computed column to re-generate the full `FileNumber` string.

**Implementation**

*With the absolute assumption that you cannot insert new files into OLD years*, here's how I would do this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NextValueForCurrentYear
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    -- Narrow surrogate key managed by Sql
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Provided during insert, or retrieved from some config table
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    -- Auto incrementing sequence
    SequenceNoInYear INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SequenceNoInYear 
                DEFAULT NEXT value FOR NextValueForCurrentYear,
    -- Computed column - can be read, generated automatically
    FileNumber AS CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + 
            CAST(SequenceNoInYear AS VARCHAR(10)),
    -- Other Columns here

    -- Ensure filenumber is unique
    CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable UNIQUE([Year], SequenceNoInYear)
);
```

All you need to do is supply the year number, and the rest will be generated, i.e

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Year) VALUES (2015);
```

If you need to start your Sequence Numbers every year from 1, then you will need to [reset the Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx) every year.

[Sql Fiddle of this here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8861d/4)

The Unique Key constraint on `[Year], SequenceNoInYear` will guard against inserting old years once the sequence number has been reset.

Comment: firstly thanks for your reply, in sql fiddle its working but i want to ask the file number, its not id number on table, i think it wont be unique in this way am i right i mean will it be increase automatically if it will be it works and thanks:) ? but i did not understand the old years you ve mentioned. I will create another table for archive if you saying that.

Comment: Although Filenumber is unique it is not a good choice of primary key IMO. My answer shows how a unique file number can be safely derived using a sequence and a computed column although you need to reset the sequence every year. There is no need to archive the data as year and sequence are stored.

Comment: By old years I mean if we are now in 2016 the sequence has been reset so if you needed to insert a forgotten 2015 record you would need to determine a unique sequence number manually instead of using the sequence default.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   SomeDateColumn DATE,
   YourCompoundID AS RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(SomeDateColumn) AS VARCHAR(4)) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(SomeDateColumn, Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES ('20150725', Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `YourCompoundID` will contain values like `00001/2015`, `00002/2015`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably.

Comment: thanks for your reply i understand most of it but i want to ask will it be start from 1 for each year

Comment: @ulmotl: in that case, you'd need a `SEQUENCE` which is available from SQL Server **2012** onwards; you can reset a sequence when you need to, e.g. once every Jan 1 of a new year

Comment: as @StuartLC mentioned i think

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment (`identity` in T-SQL) can only be used for integers. It also limits the column in the way it can be inserted into. One way of solving your requirement might be to assign number ranges to specific years (2014,2015,etc.) and then translate these numbers back into file names in a query like: 1-1000000 for 2014, 1000001-2000000 for 2015 and so on. In a select statement you could then use something like

```
Select cast(floor(id/1000000)+2014 as char(4))+'/'+cast(id % 1000000 as varchar(6)) mykey ... from table
```

But generally speaking I believe it is better to use a separate numbering table like

```
mumtbl:
----------
year    mxidx_used
---------------------
2014       234
2015      1678
```

and use that as a lookup for new keys to be generated (and don't forget to update the max value there afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

you have to create one primary key set initial value 1233 in your case and formulate your FileID according to your requirement just run my query in your DB and try to insert name manuaaly in table you see you get your result i hope this will help you

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblStringPrimaryKey]    Script Date: 7/25/2015 3:32:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStringPrimaryKey](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1233,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileId]  AS ((CONVERT([nvarchar](10),datepart(year,getdate()))+'/')+CONVERT([nvarchar](22),[Id])),
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblStringPrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_tblStringPrimaryKey] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```